# Why does the concat method seem to ruin my Array reference

Tags: javascript

Why does this not alert a,b,c?

```
var results=[];
function test(r){
  var abc = ['a','b','c'];
  r=r.concat(abc);
}
test(results);
alert(results);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because concat does not modify the object you're calling it on. Also, the `r=r.concat(abc);` suggests you don't understand pass by reference. When you assign r to something, you're not changing what the original, passed in value is pointing to, all you're doing is updating what the variable in your function is pointing to. This will work:

```
var results=[];
function test(r){
  var abc = ['a','b','c'];
  return r.concat(abc);
}
results = test(results);
alert(results);
```

Comment: What if I want to do something after I concat the arrays?  In other words how do I get it to update the original without returning the value?  And thanks for the explanation it makes sense now.  I understand passing by reference to a certain extent, but obviously not as well as I should.

Comment: If you really wanted, `r.push.push.apply(r, abc)` would mutate the object referenced by `r` in-place.  But that's kinda ugly.

Comment: @qw3n gald I could help. To do this, you'd need to use a function which modifies the passed in variable. Checkout `push()` and `splice()`.